# Add value from a variable to a list via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have a variable that contains column-value (terms) from a page/list

```
 $terms = $page.FieldValues["Terms"];
```

where "$page" is a variable containing the site page.

I get another site page as a list item:

```
$transformedItem = Get-PnPFile -Url $myUrl -AsListItem
```

The above list item has a column "Keyword". How do I populate that column "keyword" with the variable "$terms"?

Comment: What value do you want to put into "Keyword" from $terms ?? because $terms has many fieldvalues.

Answer (score 0):

You could update the item via the following pnp cmdlets:
[Set-PnPListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps#examples)

thanks